# Can't import Optuna

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, optuna

I am trying to import Optuna on Jupyter Notebook. I have previously installed `pytorch-2.0.1`. I have tried to downgrade pytorch as well as uninstalling and reinstalling Optuna as well as sqlalchemy. The error I am getting now when running `import Optuna` is:

```py
"ImportError: cannot import name 'NOT_EXTENSION' from 'sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces"
```

Does anybody know what the error could be and if there is a fix to this?

Comment: Can you show the versions of the relevant libraries, that you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that it may help you

```
pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy
```

Comment: I already tried that, it did not help.

Comment: could you share all version of libraries(sqlalchemy, optuna) and python version and platform which you use?